# How to get code coverage using coveralls and rspec-puppet?

Tags: rspec, code-coverage, puppet, coveralls

[This branch](https://github.com/030/puppet-otto/compare/gh6_code_coverage_coveralls?expand=1) has been created in order to get code coverage using Coveralls:

**.coveralls.yml**

```
service_name: travis-ci
```

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'coveralls'

Coveralls.wear! do
  add_filter '/spec/fixtures/modules/otto/'
end
```

A code coverage report is created, but the .pp files seems to be excluded. How to get code coverage using Coveralls?

Comment: Are you using puppetlabs spec helper?

Comment: @MattSchuchard [Yes](https://github.com/030/puppet-otto/compare/gh6_code_coverage_coveralls?expand=1#diff-93830fa29d616f7c87903d08b5b1b29aR2). The code coverage is shown when `rspec-puppet` is run, but coveralls seems to run another command.

Comment: So I haven't really done this before, but I notice you are deviating a good bit from the documentation in puppetlabs spec helper and rspec puppet for how to do this. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @MattSchuchard That seems to be changed indeed. I have changed the snippet (see branch), but the issue persists

Comment: Your Rakefile seems to be missing a `suite` task unless I am mistaken. The direct copy/paste from the RSpec Puppet doc is expecting that task to be executed before performing the manifest code coverage.